# Ugly fonts in Anaconda Spyder (possible issue with PyQt4/PyQt5)

Tags: pyqt4, anaconda, pyqt5, spyder

I installed Anaconda 2.5 (I tried both versions, for Python 2 and Python 3) on a brand-new installation of Ubuntu Mate 15.10, and I have a nasty issue with the fonts in Spyder (the fonts of the editor as well as those in the menus look pretty ugly).

I also installed Spyder as a *standalone* application (outside the Anaconda environment): in this case everything is fine and the fonts look very nice.

I think that the issue with Anaconda's Spyder is due to lack of anti-aliasing, and my guess is that the problem is connected to the Qt library. For Anaconda2'Spyder, PyQt4 is used:

- Python 2.7.11 64bits, Qt 4.8.7, PyQt4 (API v2) 4.11.4 on Linux

For the standalone Spyder (which I built from source), instead, PyQt5 is used:

- Python 2.7.10 64bits, Qt 5.4.2, PyQt5 5.4.2 on Linux)

It is worth noting that Ubuntu Mate 15.10's stock python comes with PyQt5, while Anaconda's Spyder works with PQt4.

On a different machine, with Ubuntu 14.04 (Unity, not Mate), which is shipped with PyQt4 (no PyQt5 is present on the system), Anaconda's Spyder is not affected by the issue.

Does my guess sound reasonable? And (most important), how can I solve the problem with Anaconda's Spyder on Ubuntu Mate 15.10?

PS. I am actually experiencing the issue on three different machines with Ubuntu Mate 15.10, not just on the new PC with the brand-new installation that I mentioned at the beginning!